# C# FTP ListDirectoryDetails Problem

Tags: c#, ftp

I try to read file list from FTP from direcotry that contains over 1000 files.

I do it like this :

```
    public static FtpWebRequest GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.UseBinary = false;
        req.UsePassive = true;
        return req;
    }

    public static bool CheckConnection()
    {
        FtpWebResponse respSize = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP = GetRequest(@"ftp://myftp.com");
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            respSize = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            respSize.Close();
            respSize = null;
            reqFTP.GetResponse().Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        //...
        }
        finally
        {
            if (respSize != null)
                respSize.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I get an error:

> The remote server returned an error:
>
> (451) Local error in processing.
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object
> obj)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object
> obj)
>
> at
> System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean
> disposing)
>
> at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>
> at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
>
> at
> System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream
> pooledStream)
>
> at
> System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream
> pooledStream, Object owningObject,
> Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean
> canReuse)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage
> stage)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object
> obj)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object
> obj)
>
> at
> System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception
> e)
>
> at
> System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebRequest.DataStreamClosed(CloseExState
> closeState)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState
> closeState)
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean
> disposing)
>
> at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>
> at
> System.Net.FtpWebResponse.Close()
>
> at CheckConnection()

does anyone knows what is going on ?

regards
Marcin

Comment: Does it work with a smaller number of files?

Comment: yes, it works with small number of files

Answer (score 1):

From RhinoSoft (makers of the FTP software Serv-U):

> "A 451 reply code may be sent in response to any command initiating a file transfer. It is a transient negative response, which means the error condition is a temporary one. It is usually sent in response to the server encountering an unexpected local error when processing data it is transferring or receiving. In this case, the client is encouraged to restart the FTP transaction and try again." [[1]](http://www.rhinosoft.com/respcode.asp?resp=451&Prod=s)

So, it may be an issue with communication between your software and the FTP server, not necessarily an issue with your software itself.

It can't hurt to increase the length of the `Timeout` property of `FtpWebRequest`, but that's not likely to be the cause based on my research.

Comment: do you have any idea?  this 'temporary' problem occures every time.
maybe there are some flags on the server that administrator has to set up?

Comment: I tested your code against an FTP server with 2000 files. Unfortunately, the error is fairly generic and it's being generated on the FTP server, not in your software. Your best bet is going to be to work with the server owner. Do you have any problems with standard FTP clients?

Comment: One last shot in the dark: Try turning req.UsePassive to "false".